# How to use sendSignedTransaction without waiting for confirmation?

Tags: web3.py, web3js-v1.x

I am sending ether to multiple accounts and I want to send them without delay or waiting for confirmation of previous transaction.

```js
const fs   = require("fs");
const os   = require("os");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const net  = require('net');

const NODE_ADDRESS = "IPC";
const SEND_ACCOUNT = "ACC";
const PRIVATE_KEY  = "PRI";
const INPUT_FILE   = "CSV";

async function run() {
    const web3      = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS, net);
    let nonce_count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(SEND_ACCOUNT);

    const lines     = fs.readFileSync(INPUT_FILE, {encoding: "utf8"}).split(os.EOL);
    for (const line of lines) {
        const [id, address, balance] = line.split(",");
        const options = {
            to       : address,
            value    : balance,
            gasPrice : 1000000000,
            gas      : 21000,
            nonce    : nonce_count
        };
        const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, PRIVATE_KEY);
        const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
        console.log("Address:",address,"Balance:",balance,"Nonce:",nonce_count);
        nonce_count++
    }
}

run();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean "Here is my web3.js code"...

Comment: I mean not literally my code :joy:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
const promises = [];
for (const line of lines) {
    ...
    promises.push(web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction));
    nonce_count++;
}
await Promise.all(promises);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed code

```js
const fs   = require("fs");
const os   = require("os");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const net  = require('net');

const NODE_ADDRESS = "IPC";
const SEND_ACCOUNT = "ACC";
const PRIVATE_KEY  = "PRI";
const INPUT_FILE   = "CSV";

async function run() {
    const web3      = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS, net);
    let nonce_count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(SEND_ACCOUNT);

    const lines     = fs.readFileSync(INPUT_FILE, {encoding: "utf8"}).split(os.EOL);
    for (const line of lines) {
        const [id, address, balance] = line.split(",");
        const promises = [];
        const options = {
            to       : address,
            value    : balance,
            gasPrice : 1000000000,
            gas      : 21000,
            nonce    : nonce_count
        };
        const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, PRIVATE_KEY);
        const txHash = await web3.utils.sha3(signed.rawTransaction);
        promises.push(web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction));
        console.log("Address:",address,"Balance:",balance,"Nonce:",nonce_count,"TX Hash:",txHash);
        nonce_count++
    }
    await Promise.all(promises);
}

run();
```